# Как защититься от фрейма?

Tags: php

Есть страница, на которой при определенных условиях выполняет переадресацию на другой сайт.
Если эту страницу вставить во фрейм:

```
<iframe src="http://site.ru/page.php" width="500" height="500"
  style="border:1px solid lightgrey;">
```

переадресация так же выполниться в во фрейме.

Каким образом сделать чтобы это не работало во фрейме?
То есть нужно такое условие:

```
if (если_это_фрейм) {
    exit;
} else {
    header("location: http://go.ru");
}
```

Comment: какое событие на странице приводит к переходу?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin header("location: "); , просто на php проверяю куки и если их нет идет переход

Comment: сайты то оба ваши?

Comment: @teran мой сайт который хочу закрыть от фрейма. тот на который ставят фрейм - чужой

Answer (score 0):

На всех страницах своего сайта выдаете заголовок:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Можете это делать через php так: `header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');`

[Тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) больше информации по заголовку.

Comment: не помогает. страницу скрывает но php код на ней выполянет

Comment: @Денис, браузер-то получает заголовок установленный вами? Откройте инструменты разработчика в браузере на вкладке сеть и посмотрите в заголовки ответа от сервера.

Comment: вставил в самое начало страницы header("X-Frame-Options: Deny");

Comment: @Денис, браузер-то получает заголовок установленный вами? Откройте инструменты разработчика в браузере на вкладке сеть и посмотрите в заголовки ответа от сервера.

Comment: X-Frame-Options параметра нигде не вижу

Comment: @Денис, значит у вас уже идет вывод данных в браузер до отправки заголовка.

Comment: @Денис, можете его настроить в apache/nginx https://habrahabr.ru/company/hosting-cafe/blog/315802/#11

Comment: проверил заголовок - передает. но код все равно выполняет

Comment: @Денис, вы на localhost тестируете?

Comment: нет, на хостинге уже

Comment: @Денис, значит у вас супер браузер, который не поддерживает стандарты ;)

Comment: консоль хрома ловит такую ошибку: `Refused to display 'http://go.ru' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Comment: то есть заголовок этот видит и он запрешает переадресацию, но при этом php код который ниже на странице - он все равно выполняется

Comment: @Денис, действительно, страница формируется полностью и отправляется браузеру. А вот браузер ее просто не отображает. Что-то мне это не нравится.

Comment: да, странно. может так и должно быть?

Comment: @Денис, вероятно, что так и должно быть, раз браузер запрашивает всю страницу (метод GET) и только потом в ответ узнает, что ее отображать нельзя. Вот если бы он запрашивал первым запросом только заголовки (методом HEAD) и в дальнейшем не запрашивал тело страницы, вот было бы хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - использовать `_GET` параметр

```
<iframe src="http://site.ru/page.php?frame=1" width="500" height="500"
  style="border:1px solid lightgrey;">
```

.

```
if (!isset($_GET['frame'])) {
  header("location: http://go.ru");
exit;
```

Comment: не вариант, фрейм на чужом сайте